# Given a 5x5 matrix, check if all elements on anti diagonal appear on the main diagonal (conflicting test case)

Tags: c, matrix

I did easily solve this problem, but I have a conflicting test case for which I believe to be a mistake from the question author. The code I've written is as follows:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int inar(int t, int *a,int l)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < l; i ++)
        if(a[i] == t)
            return 1;
    return 0;
}

int solve(int a[][5], int d)
{
    int md[d];
    for(int i = 0, j = 0; i < d && j < d; i++,j++)
        md[i] = a[i][j];
    for(int i =0; i < d ; i++)
        for(int j = 0; j  < d; j++)
            if (i + j == d - 1)
                if(!inar(a[i][j],md,d))
                    return 0;
    return 1;
}

int main()
{
    int a[5][5] = {
    {1,2,5,-1,1},
    {4,8,4,1,6},
    {2,4,6,7,8},
    {3,4,7,1,2},
    {8,8,11,9,3}
    };
    printf("%d\n",solve(a,5));
}
```

For this example, the code returns 0, as it should, as there is an element on the anti diagonal, 4, that doesnt appear on the main diagonal, 1 8 6 1 3. However, in the test case with this exact example, the code should apparently return 1? I do not think this is correct. I am also pretty sure that the question text reads exactly how i typed it. I believe this is a mistake on their part, however I'd like to hear if anyone else would have a different opinion.

I implemented the solution which I believe to be correct both code-wise and intuition-wise, but the test example says otherwise.

**Full text problem**

Given 5x5 matrix as input, write a function that checks whether all elements on anti diagonal also appear on main diagonal. The elements on diagonals may repeat.

**Example:**

Input matrix

```
1 2 5 -1 1
4 8 4 1 6
2 4 6 7 8
3 4 7 1 2
8 8 11 9 3
```

Output: `1`

Comment: As a unrelated side note, using brace-less loop/if bodies is often asking for trouble. You'll save yourself a lot of squinting and tears if you use braces `{ }`  even in the single-statement case

Comment: In your code, the main diagonal has 18613, the anti diagonal has 11648, so they don't match. Without a link to the actual problem, there's not much more to say.

Comment: Also, what standard of C are you using? In C99+, you can include `stdbool.h` and use `bool`/`true`/`false` instead of bare ints

Comment: @user3386109 i have updated the question with the full problem text.

Comment: The question (I mean the one presented to you, not your question, here) is unclear. It doesn't specify what the return value should be. For example, maybe it should follow the 'pattern' of the `strcmp` functions and return the number of elements on the antidiagonal that aren't present in the leading diagonal. In that case, `1` would be correct for the example you give.

Comment: Why do you use two nested loops for a one-dimensional search?  you are running a loop just to use only one valid pass on it (when indices match on a diagonal)  anti-diagonal elements are the ones that make i + j to add N (or 5 in this case) and the main diagonal elements are the ones that are equal (they subtract to 0)